# Using ASP.NET updatePanel I have Error parsing near <!DOCTYPE html P'. Shall I give up?

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

Wether with IE or Firefox, when I'm in a Ajax enabled webform that uses Updatepanel, I end up having the nasty error message:  Error parsing near <!DOCTYPE html P'

On IE I can see the "Error on page" message down left.
With Firefox no error... But in both cases there is no more reaction to user's click... Until user navigates outside the faulty page.

I try everything I found googling that:

Adding Trace="false"

Adding enableEventValidation="false"

Replacing single quotes with ampersand apos;

Nothing to do. The annoying thing is that the page will react fine during a few bunch of user clicks, displaying an image, then another one (according to the click) etc. And suddendly, the UpdatePanel is dead.

Any clue? Its urgent, thanks Gurus...

Comment: Update: I got rid of the UpdatePanel and have same error... Happens when I click on a ASP:LinkButton that fires a click event where I make an ASP:Panel visible=true in code behind...

Comment: I got rid of the UpdatePanel and now that I updated the page.aspx on the server (! lol) the page "works" fine...

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but the following might be helpful to someone:  http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/general-discussions/intermittent-pagerequestmanagerparsererrorexception.aspx

Specifically, regarding the X-MicrosoftAjax header: "Can you verify that you are not behind an overly restrictive proxy or firewall that may be tampering or deleting that extra headers?"

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this problem on my dev machine and it turned out to be due to my enabling SSL cookies and then trying to access the site over HTTP - the authentication cookie wasn't being sent, so the site was responding as if I were a logged-out user, which in this case meant sending the full front page of the site (the 'DOCTYPE' in the error message is of course the first line of a full page rather than a partial update).

So to be clear, if you have this problem and you're using unsecured HTTP, look for

`<httpCookies ... requireSSL="true" />`

in your web.config and try commenting it out (you may also need to clear cookies on your browser).